# How does std::chrono::duration default constructed?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration) says `The default constructor is defaulted`. I also checked the `C++14 draft`, it said nothing on the default constructor, except the declaration: `constexpr duration() = default;`

When I run the following code, I was surprised.

```
chrono::seconds s;
cout << s.count() << endl;
```

Each time I run it, the program prints some arbitrary numbers: `140737364037104`, `140737078676496` and so on.

It seems that `s` does NOT well initialized. Then I checked my compiler (GCC 4.8)'s implementation for `std::chrono::duration`. This class has a data member (i.e. the `count`) of int type without any in-class initializer. And the constructor is default constructed. So the data member is, in fact, uninitialized. And that's why the program always prints some arbitrary numbers.

The followings are my questions:

1. Is that the right behavior? Or the compiler should give the data member an in-class initializer?
2. If that's the right behavior, why does the standard NOT specify a default value, say `0`, for `std::chrono::duration`?

Comment: What's the question? This is no different from `int a;`. If you understand default-initialziation in that context, then you understand the `duration` situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Default constructed durations are not zero initialized due to optimization.**

Quoting **Vicente J. Botet Escriba** from same question in [ISO C++ Discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/OcGX7Yj3meI):

> Hi, I guess is to follow the pattern don't pay for what you don't use,
>   but Howard would explain it better.
>
> If you want the representation to be default initialized to zero, you
>   can just provide one that do that
>
> `std::chrono::duration<MyInt> d; // MyInt default constructor initialize the value to zero.`

It is confirmed and further explained by lead designer and author of `<chrono>` time utilities (**Howard Hinnant**)

Comment: Here is another syntax for zero-initialization:  `chrono::seconds s{};`

Comment: Make sense. Thanks!

Comment: @HowardHinnant is that guaranteed to initialize `s` to zero`? By what wording? I looked in cppreference, it does not contain such a hint.

Comment: Yes.  Braced initialization with zero arguments for a type with a compiler-supplied default constructor is guaranteed to perform braced initialization on all non-static data members and bases.  `seconds` is guaranteed to have a signed integral data member, and braced initialization on that is guaranteed to perform zero-initialization.  (This is when I fell in love with `= default` ;-) ).

Comment: This sounds like the inner concerns of the type are allowed to spill into the using code here. Shouldn't it be irrelevant whether capsulated rep type initializes itself? It is the outer duration class that we are dealing with. It seems uncommon for std types to allow themselves to be initialized into arbitrary state.