# std::cout print different result of a chrono duration under 32/64 bit

Tags: c++, c++17, c++-chrono

I made a simple Timer class using `std::chrono`

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Timer
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point last;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::duration duration;
    bool started{};
public:
    Timer(bool start = false)
    {
        if (start)
        {
            last = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            started = true;
            std::cout<<"started\n";
        }
    }
    void pause()
    {
        if (started)
        {
            std::cout<<"paused\n";
            duration += (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - last);
            started = false;
        }
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Timer const& t);
    ~Timer()
    {
        pause();
        std::cout << *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cerr << sizeof(size_t) << '\n'; //for indicating 32 or 64 bit
    Timer t{true};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{ 1 });
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Timer const& t)
{
    os << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t.duration).count() << " ms.\n";
    return os;
}
```

When using `-m32` flag to compile 32 bit in *GCC*, it gives ridiculous result:
[link](https://godbolt.org/z/AT-qEz)

```
4
started
paused
577755959817856 ms.
```

But when compiling to 64 bit, the result seems normal: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/bptqR6)

```
8
started
paused
1004260 ms.
```

EDIT: Yes `ms` is a little bit misleading here, **should be `µs`**, but I am lazy to find `µ`

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402944/how-does-stdchronoduration-default-constructed) for an explanation of `duration`'s default constructor. Basically, it is made to behave like a fundamental arithmetic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just have UB on this line,

```
duration += (std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - last);
```

because `duration` is not initalized.

If you initialize the `duration` member

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::duration duration{};
```

everything works fine.

Comment: @walnut So it *has* to be value-initialized?

Comment: Oh  I am stupid. My mistake was that a defaulted default constructor still causes value-initialization to zero-initialize first, which would not be true for a non-defaulted default constructor. So everything is fine.

Comment: @walnut aah, ok, was very confused for a second :p

Answer (score 3):

The problem has occurred because you didn't initialize your `duration`, hence UB.

See https://godbolt.org/z/qTqLBC